# Get MySQL value to place in URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form in which once the user click the submit button, he is sent to save.php page. On the save.php page, the info of the form are sent to the MySQL table. However, on the save.php page, I have placed a rederict, to bring the user to a unique page, where he can see the info he just entered.

To do that, I place in the table with the info of the user a unique code, to place in the URL of the «unique page». Here is the portion of the code that involve what I talk about.

```
 $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_event (x, x, x, x, x, Confirm_code) VALUES('".$x."', '".$_SESSION['x']."', '".$x."', '".$x."', '".$x."', '".$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand())). "'); ");
    if($registerquery)

    {
        echo "<h1>Congrats!</h1>";
        echo "<p>All perfect!</p>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=show2.php?confirm_code=<?php echo $registerquery[Confirm_code];?> />";
}
```

My problem is that the confirm_code never show in the URL. So, the unique page neither. How can I make the Confirm Code show in the URL?

Comment: use `show2.php?confirm_code=<?php echo $confirm_code; ?>`

Comment: You can't create a php variable inside a `mysql_query()` function.

Comment: So how should I do that insted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confirm code is never showing, as your query is most likely failing. You could use `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of your query to verify - `$registerquery = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`

Create your variable outside you query, and then add it to your query and meta string.

```
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_event (x, x, x, x, x, Confirm_code) VALUES('".$x."', '".$_SESSION['x']."', '".$x."', '".$x."', '".$x."', '".$confirm_code. "'); ");
if($registerquery){
        echo "<h1>Congrats!</h1>";
        echo "<p>All perfect!</p>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=show2.php?confirm_code=".$confirm_code."' />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting into MySQL and not selecting. $registerquery variable does not contain the code. 
So before that query save the Confirm code in some php variable.

```
$temp_code = Confirm_code; //whatever the code is
```

then

```
 $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_event (x, x, x, x, x, Confirm_code) VALUES('".$x."', '".$_SESSION['x']."', '".$x."', '".$x."', '".$x."', '".$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand())). "'); ");
if($registerquery)

{
    echo "<h1>Congrats!</h1>";
    echo "<p>All perfect!</p>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=show2.php?confirm_code=<?php echo $temp_code;?> />"; }
```

use that  temporary variable instead of $registerquery[Confirm_code]

Another way will be first inserting and then selecting that I think you really don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean using your `$confirm_code` variable? Because you are inserting into the database, not *selecting*.

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=show2.php?confirm_code=' . $confirm_code . '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value to $confirm_code at the same time you insert it into the database. Just change:

```
$registerquery[Confirm_code]
```

to

```
$confirm_code
```